# Redirection to named file descriptor buggy inside functions

Tags: bash, io-redirection, function, file-descriptors

Bash has a feature where it will pick a file descriptor number for you and assign it to a variable.

```bsh
$ exec {fd}>foo.txt
$ echo "$fd"
11
$ echo "bar" >&$fd
$ cat foo.txt
bar
```

This feature works great with bash 4.4, but I've encountered a snag with bash 4.2 when I use it inside a function. Here's a minimal demonstration:

```bsh
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
$ (func() { echo 1>&$fd; }; type func)
func is a function
func () 
{ 
    echo &>$fd
}
$ (func() { echo 2>&$fd; }; type func)
func is a function
func () 
{ 
    echo 2>&$fd
}
```

Notice that in the first test `1>&$fd` became `&>$fd`. If `$fd` were 11, instead of redirecting to fd 11 it would redirect to a *file* named `11`. However, it's only with stdout. stderr doesn't have this bug, as the second test shows.

Nor does bash 4.4:

```bsh
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ (func() { echo 1>&$fd; }; type func)
func is a function
func () 
{ 
    echo 1>&$fd
}
```

It looks like this is a bug that was fixed. Is that true? And more importantly, can you suggest any workarounds?

Comment: Note that in bash, arguments to redirections still undergo word splitting, so you'd still need `1>&"$fd"` and with those extra quotes, even bash 5 or the current git head exhibits the bug, so it looks like it's not fully fixed.

Comment: even though `type func` shows `echo &>$fd`, in my test with 4.2, the function behaves as if it was `echo >&$fd`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround change `>&` to `1<&`. It avoids the bug while preserving the desired behavior. Whether fds are opened for reading or writing doesn't matter when duplicating them. [`dup2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) doesn't care.

```bsh
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
$ (func() { echo 1<&$fd; }; type func)
func is a function
func () 
{ 
    echo 1<&$fd
}
```

Comment: This is what I came up with as a workaround. I'm definitely curious if there are other better ones.